# How require() works in JavaScript and how its usage affects console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, console.log

Could someone explain how require() and console.log work in javascript?
I have a code snipped saying something close to this one:

```
var somevar = require('C:/Users/Me/Folder/SomeFolder/somefile.js');
console.log(somevar);
```

In the console I see the following:

```
{ _maxListeners: 0,
  reset: [Function],
  verify: [Function],
  report: [Function],
  getSource: [Function],
  getSourceLines: [Function],
  getAllComments: [Function],
  getComments: [Function],
  getJSDocComment: [Function],
  getAncestors: [Function],
  getNodeByRangeIndex: [Function],
  getScope: [Function],
  markVariableAsUsed: [Function],
  getFilename: [Function],
  defineRule: [Function],
  defineRules: [Function],
  defaults: [Function] }
```

somefile.js here is a huge file with javascript code (more then 32 000 lines). To be precise it's ESLint in my case.

Why does it print only these results in console? There are many more functions in somefile.js then listed above and I expected to see more.

And after simply requiring eslint module from Node.js `var eslintfile = require('eslint');` the output in console is slightly different:

```
 { linter: 
       { _maxListeners: 0,
         reset: [Function],
         verify: [Function],
         report: [Function],
         getSource: [Function],
         getSourceLines: [Function],
         getAllComments: [Function],
         getComments: [Function],
         getJSDocComment: [Function],
         getAncestors: [Function],
         getNodeByRangeIndex: [Function],
         getScope: [Function],
         markVariableAsUsed: [Function],
         getFilename: [Function],
         defineRule: [Function],
         defineRules: [Function],
         defaults: [Function] },
      cli: { execute: [Function] },
      CLIEngine: [Function: CLIEngine] }
```

Why is it so?

There is no purpose whatsoever in the code above. I was just playing with it. I only need an explanation. Any suggestions, links and thoughts are much appreciated.

And what should I do to see all functions in the code and find one I need to print it then in console or write in a different file?

Comment: That "somefile.js" and the main script of `eslint` might have different versions of ESLint. Can you check that?

Comment: @E_net4 I just named the file differently in the code snipped here. Of course both are the latest versions of ESLint. And in reality eslint file in the first example is 0.20.0. That's why I decided to ask how exactly require affects console.log. I though I simply don't understand it.

Comment: Just another clarification: where did you get the first file? Are you running it in a browser or also in Node.js?

Comment: @E_net4 from node.js. In order to get a new version I type npm install and then eslint test. After that a new build folder is created with the latest version of eslint

Comment: So I figured. My answer will hopefully cover your issue entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `require` function will only retrieve whatever the module is exporting (through the `module.exports` object, which is typical in a CommonJS module). Since the general behavior of `console.log` on objects is to inspect them up to a certain depth, the explanation that you seem to be requesting is that the two modules are actually different and exporting a slightly different range of attributes. Although both are the same version of ESLint, the first file is the bundled (browserify'd in this case) ESLint API, which does not contain the CLI engine. This can be found out by observing the [package.json](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v0.20.0/package.json) and [Makefile.js](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v0.20.0/Makefile.js) in the ESLint repository.

When `require`ing the library by its package name in Node, the "main" script is loaded, which according to package.json, is ["./lib/api.js"](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v0.20.0/lib/api.js). This script will load both the linter and a few extra objects that relate to the command line interface.

By looking at "Makefile.js" in [line 44](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v0.20.0/Makefile.js#L444), you can see that the building operation with browserify will instead bundle "eslint.js" and its dependencies, without including anything else (the CLI part, that is). This bundling [is also triggered by the `test` command](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/v0.20.0/Makefile.js#L284L302), which was invoked by the "test" script in the package.

In short, the two modules are different, even though consisting of the same package. This leads to a different output by `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

`require` will return a reference to whatever is the module places into its `exports` property.

You are saying that the file contains many more functions than what you see when you print the object with `console.log`.  Number of functions in the file doesn't matter.  It's the `exports` that matter.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

As for `console.log`, it will call `util.inspect` on the supplied object to build a string representation of it.  It writes to the process's `STDOUT` (standard output) stream.

https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data

Answer (score -1):

console.log() prints the value of whatever is in the parentheses into the console (which is only visible by the developer).

Comment: Perhaps you should focus your answer on how `require` does not affect `console.log()` and why the operation seems to be printing different objects.